# How can I restart the game by pressing "r"?

Tags: python, ursina

My plans are to restart the game / reset the character to the middle of the map.

```
import keyboard as kb
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

app = Ursina()
window.fps_counter.enabled = False
player = FirstPersonController()
Sky()

boxes = []

def random_color():
red = random.Random().random() * 20
green = random.Random().random() * 255
blue = random.Random().random() * 20
return color.rgb(red, green, blue)

def add_box(position):
boxes.append(
Button(
parent=scene,
model='cube',
origin=0.5,
color=random_color(),
position=position,
texture='grass'
)
)

for x in range(20):
for y in range(20):
add_box( (x, 0, y) )

def input(key):
for box in boxes:
if box.hovered:
if key == "right mouse down":
add_box(box.position + mouse.normal)
if key == "left mouse down":
boxes.remove(box)
destroy(box)
if kb.is_pressed("escape"):
exit()
if kb.is_pressed("shift"):
player.speed = 15
else:
player.speed = 7

app.run()
```

I can´t find help for this issue in the whole world of the internet. Please help me.

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: While I am not familiar with ursina, your solution already works, ```if kb.is_pressed("r"):  do something```. Also, please do not post random characters, instead you can give us more specifics on your problem

Comment: Also, might I add, its is a terrible practice to do ```from something import *```, when importing multiple files, this may cause a function error, as two functions may have the same name

Comment: This question in its current form is too broad. Please review [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean with reset? Reset the hole game or just the player position?

To reset player position you can do something like this:

```py
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()

# Change this to whatever your player is. In your case First person controller 
player = Entity(model = 'cube')

player_reset_position = (0,0,0)
def input(key):
    if key == 'r':
        player.position = player_reset_position

app.run()
```

Your code with some fixes:

```py
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

app = Ursina()
window.fps_counter.enabled = False
player = FirstPersonController()
Sky()

boxes = []

def random_color():
    red = random.Random().random() * 20
    green = random.Random().random() * 255
    blue = random.Random().random() * 20
    return color.rgb(red, green, blue)

def add_box(position):
    boxes.append(
    Button(
        parent=scene,
        model='cube',
        origin=0.5,
        color=random_color(),
        position=position,
        texture='grass'
    )
)

for x in range(20):
    for y in range(20):
        add_box((x, 0, y))

player_reset_position = (5,10,5)

def input(key):
    for box in boxes:
        if box.hovered:
            if key == "right mouse down":
                add_box(box.position + mouse.normal)
            if key == "left mouse down":
                boxes.remove(box)
                destroy(box)

    if key == ("escape"):
        exit()
    if key == ("shift"):
        player.speed = 15
    else:
        player.speed = 7

    if key == 'r':
        player.position = player_reset_position
app.run()
```

I have changed *indentation* and your *input function* where you had `if kb.is_pressed("escape"):` to `if key == "escape":`